# vertical space between paragraphs and `topsep` in \usepackage{enumitem} cancel each other out

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, incompatibility, enumitem

I'm using `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` to insert vertical space between the paragraphs in my document. However this create a conflict with my list environments. To solve that I am using the `enumitem` package to set the space between the last line before my itemize environment and my first item to `=0pt` however, the paragraph spacing created with `\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}` cancel this out. I can get at it by setting `topsep` to ~ `-9pt`, but them I loose the spacing between the last item and the next paragraph (MWE is below). I have deliberately chosen `noitemsep` as I also want less spacing between the individual item, I would like to keep this.

[image: Space I am trying to get rid off]

```
\documentclass{article}

% insert vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} 

% Modifies itemized lists with enumitem http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt} % , topsep=-9pt

 % http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext/blindtext.pdf
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document} 

\blindtext

\noindent
This is the things cancel each other out:
% space I would like to get rid of is here!
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item
\item insert vertical space between paragraphs
\item \verb|[topsep=0pt]| in \verb| \usepackage{enumitem} |
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}` to your `itemize` options:

```
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% insert vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

% Modifies itemized lists with enumitem http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
 \setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}} % , topsep=-9pt

 % http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext/blindtext.pdf
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\noindent
This is the things cancel each other out:
% space I would like to get rid of is here!
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item
\item insert vertical space between paragraphs
\item \verb|[topsep=0pt]| in \verb| \usepackage{enumitem} |
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you for a great solution! I did however not illustrate my document fully in my MWE so I ended up with a new (minor) issue. I have created [a new question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229016/uniformness-spacing-around-headings-with-special-case-of-usepackageenumitem) where I address this. Thanks!

Comment: @uT5r You're welcome. I've answered your new question, too.

Comment: I just want to say thank you. I have been looking for this solution for a while! I now use the command: 
`\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*, nosep, before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}}` in my document.

Answer (score 0):

karlkoeller's answer works great for some time, but you should be aware of the following:

Using negative `vspace` for the environment can have unwanted side effects as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351398/page-content-overflows-footnote-area/351567#351567) happened to me. The manipulation of `vspace` leads to Latex calculating the wrong vertical size and can lead to the page content overflowing for example the footnote area.

Instead you should manipulate `\topsep` before (and after, if necessary) the environment, to make it consume less vertical space.