# Uniform spacing around headings with special case of `\usepackage{enumitem}’ and `\baselineskip`

Tags: spacing, sectioning, enumitem

This question is a follow-up question to [my question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229006/vertical-space-between-paragraphs-and-topsep-in-usepackageenumitem-cancel-e). [@karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27635/karlkoeller)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229007/71924) fully answered my question. However in my document I have some places where the itemized list is placed directly after a `\subsection`. This leads to the spacing around subsections not being uniform. I would like to mach the spacing around the *The Bee's Knees* heading so that the other `\subsection`s set the same spacing. Here an illumination of my problem and MWE below.

[image: New ununiformness]

```
\documentclass{article}

% insert vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} 

% Modifies itemized lists with enumitem http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, before={\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}} 

 % http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext/blindtext.pdf
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document}

\section*{\centering{New ununiformness}}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt. Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien. 

\noindent
This is the things cancel each other out:
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item
\item insert vertical space between paragraphs
\item \verb|[topsep=0pt]| in \verb| \usepackage{enumitem} |
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{\centering{Not too funky situation in my actual document}}

Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt. 

\subsection*{\centering{The Bee's Knees}}
% spacing I like and would like to copy to my other \subsection
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item, that is a bit longer to illustrate how close to the subsection heading compared to above.
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{\centering{Random Randomness}}

Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt. Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it? `\test` is just a marker, visually showing the distance between the base line of `\section` and the first line of text after it. Try running it and see what happens if you set `\parskip` to `0pt`.

Comment: @daleif, I have, that was the first ting I did. It is however a bit more advanced then what I can handle, I am simply trying to solve my concrete problem for now. If I let people have a working example that mimics my case they are also free to suggest alternative solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, to obtain centered titles don't do things like

```
\subsection*{\centering{Not too funky situation in my actual document}}
```

but load the package `sectsty` and issue

```
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
```

Then, to achieve what you want, first of all, change your `\setlist` to

```
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, before={\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fi}}
```

load the package `titlesec` and define

```
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{-1ex plus .2ex}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% insert vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

% Modifies itemized lists with enumitem http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt, before={\ifdim\lastskip>0pt\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fi}}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{-1ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section*{New ununiformness}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt. Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien.

\noindent
This is the things cancel each other out:
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item
\item insert vertical space between paragraphs
\item \verb|[topsep=0pt]| in \verb| \usepackage{enumitem} |
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Not too funky situation in my actual document}

Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt.

\subsection*{The Bee's Knees}
% spacing I like and would like to copy to my other \subsection
\begin{itemize}
\item dummy first item, that is a bit longer to illustrate how close to the subsection heading compared to above.
\item dummy last item
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Random Randomness}

Aliquam ornare diam vitae nisl pharetra, quis tincidunt augue finibus. Etiam dignissim lectus eu odio viverra tincidunt. Nulla ultricies finibus magna, et rutrum nisi volutpat quis. Praesent eget eros sapien.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. (@daleif have a look at this)

Comment: @uT5r You're always welcome!

Comment: I just found out that it is possible to simply. I can add `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{}` and then you do not load the package `sectsty`. Is there a good reason why you did not do that?

Comment: @uT5r With `sectsty` it is automatic for all sectioning commands. With `titlesec` you have to make a declaration for each one.

Comment: @uT5r Anyway, if you don't want to load `sectsty` add also `\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{}`. I don't know if you're also using `\subsubsections`...

Comment: You are right, I did need to add `\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{}` and `\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{}` the two sections types I am using (cf. [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53341/71924)).

Comment: @uT5r Note that for `\section` you have to use `\Large` and not `\large`